# Are unhelpful flag responses automated?

Tags: support, flagging

When I first started using this site, I raised a flag that was later deemed as unhelpful. I now know this was because I had used the incorrect flag type (being 'requires moderator intervention' rather than 'needs improvement'), but was given this text as the reason:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

I clicked the link, had a quick look through the page, and was annoyed because I didn't  understand why my flag was denied but the post was still closed. At this point, I didn't know what I had done wrong, so I flagged another off-topic question with the same flag type. It was rejected, and given the exact same response as was given to the other one, so I gave the help centre page another look - this time thoroughly - and saw where it had mentioned the part that explained off-topic questions. However, the response to my flags did not help me to arrive at this conclusion, and since both had the exact same text, I wondered if they were automated. Are they, or are they written by moderators? And if they are automated, can they be changed to something more helpful?

Comment: I've posted a feature request to clarify the help center: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384095/241919.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is one of the canned responses for a declined flag.**

Unfortunately, I just realized that the help center doesn't really explain what "standard flags" means, and it's not the first time [someone got confused with it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290507/241919)

Just to make it clear, using "in need of moderator intervention" bypasses the [community review process](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review) and goes directly to the mod-only queue. While mods can close questions instantly, Stack Exchange is inherently run by the community, thus it is still a good practice to use the correct flag option so that the community can act on it (especially on larger sites).